# Is linear model the right choice in market research about satisfaction?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, python, linear-model

I am not good in statical analysis, can someone help me?

I have a dataset derived from survey whit 1 column 'Overall satisfaction',which is formed by all values from all country, (but not the same number of values x countries).

| country | overall satisfaction |
| --- | --- |
| france | 9 |
| uk | 5 |
| uk | 7 |

Ecc..

If i would to measure how much overall satisfaction is influenced by single country values, can i use linear model with overall values as dependent and single values country as indipendent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!  First you'd have to transform your country variable into a set of "dummy" variables.  In other words, one column for each country, with a zero or a one indicating whether it's that country or not.

Then just run your regression on all of those dummy variables.  Your average country-level satisfaction would be

$$
satisfaction_c = \hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_c country_c
$$

where $\hat\beta_0$ is the intercept and $\hat\beta_c$ is the coef for country $c$.

Note that this will return the same thing as an average of the sort implemented by the following python code: `df.groupby('country')['satisfaction'].mean()`

It becomes different from a simple average if you want to control for other variables that might influence satisfaction.